# ProgressDialog not showing up

Tags: android, progressdialog

My `ProgressDialog` is not showing.

Here's the code:

```
et.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                performSearch();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void performSearch() {
            ProgressDialog pd = null;
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Buscando...",
                    "Buscando " + et.getText() + " en GuiaColor");
            lv.setAdapter(new SearchAdapter(MainActivity.this, handler
                    .search(et.getText().toString(), 20)));
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

It works just fine, the only issue is that the Dialog does not show up.

Comment: You are calling dismiss on your ProgressDialog, don't you mean pd.show()?

Comment: I'm calling ProgressDialog.show() to create it. Then I do my query (handler.search()) and then I dismiss the Dialog.

Comment: Oh, and just adding pd.show() after creating it won't work either.

Comment: You should make your query in a background task (cf AsyncTask) and dismiss the dialog from the UI thread

Comment: But that code is executed so fast that the dialog never shows up. You should dismiss it with an handler, called by the SearchAdapter when the search is complete.

Comment: Nope, it's not executed fast. It actually makes 3 different calls to my server. It usually takes about 9-10 seconds to make the call.

Also, I tried AsyncTask and Threads, and they all failed.


I'm testing this on Ice Cream Sandwich. I've tested it on Froyo on the emulator and it just works fine. I just want it to work on ICS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code to make your query in a background thread and dismiss your dialog once the task is completed:

```
    private void performSearch() {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Buscando...", "Buscando " + et.getText() + " en GuiaColor");

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                lv.setAdapter(new SearchAdapter(MainActivity.this, handler.search(et.getText().toString(), 20)));
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Comment: That won't work. A thread cannot make changes in the UIThread. You need to use an handler to invoke the dialog.dismiss() directly on the UIThread.

Comment: That works because the `dismiss()` method can be called from any thread : "This method can be invoked safely from any thread" (from the documentation)